# Tensorflow does not activate under conda in Win10

Tags: python

I am a total newbie and hence this question. I have conda 4.3.1 and Python 3.6. I managed to get tensorflow installed and get the command line
(tensorflow) c:\windows\system32
Using the Windows Installation guide I invoked python
I tried to run the following command:

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       and I got the following message
> > >       'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> > >       operable program or batch file.
> > >       Is this because I am using Python 3.6.
> > >       Any help given will be thankfully acknowledged. I am a linguist and am a bit lost

Comment: how do you created you project? add more information. is conda is working?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you are not using python kernel, but trying to import tensorflow directly from windows cli. Open up a python kernel first by typing `python` in cmd, and then import tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given full information this is my best guess you forgot to activate tensorflow. Try these steps you will be able to run it.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
activate tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Also read this [blog](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#using_conda).

Comment: FYI tensorflow binaries are not available for python 3.6 in windows. (at least not from pypi or conda)

Comment: Windows ah. You can download python3.5

Comment: Dear all,
I downloaded and installed python 3.5 and everything ran smoothly. Many thanks for all your kind help